# Typescript. How to define that an object key is required but it could have 2 different naming?

Tags: typescript, types

Basically, I'm trying to handle the situation when I have the style object and this object must have either **maxHeight** or **height** properties. In this case, if some of those properties had been passed, the other one isn't required anymore. However, I can't find any possible way to do it via TS.
I tried to do it in this way however this solution doesn't work, unfortunately

Example:

```
type Style = {
  ['maxHeight' | 'height': string]: string | number; 
 }
```

Many thanks for any help or the appropriate documentation link!

Comment: Use a union type: `type Style = { maxHeight: string | number } | { height: string | number }`.

Comment: @Clashsoft: Please post as a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a union type:

```
type Style = 
    | { maxHeight: string | number }
    | { height: string | number }
;
```